# Recompile my code with -Xlint:unchecked.After recompiling with -Xlint , unchecked call warning appears . how do i run my program now?

Tags: java

```
/** traversing elements */
import java.util.*;  
class Traversor extends Thread
{
Enumeration e;
public Traversor(Enumeration e) 
{
this.e=e;
}
public void run()
{
System.out.println("new thread started, traversing vector  elements.....");
while(e.hasMoreElements())
{
System.out.println(e.nextElement());
try
{
Thread.sleep(4000);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{}
}

System.out.println("new thread completed");
}
}


class vectortest{  
public static void main(String args[])
{
System.out.println("main thread started, creating vector...");
Vector v=new Vector();
v.addElement("one");
v.add("three"); 
v.add(1,"two");

Enumeration e=v.elements();
System.out.println("vector created ,enumeration obtained");
Traversor th=new Traversor(e);
th.start();
System.out.println(" new thread launched , suspending main thread");

try{
Thread.sleep(1000);
 }
catch(Exception ex)
{}
System.out.println("main thread resumed,modifying vector");
v.add("four");
v.add("five");
System.out.println("vector modified, main thread completed");
}
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. Also you seem to be using the outdated classes `Vector` and `Enumeration` instead of `ArrayList` and `Iterator`, are you following some very old tutorial/book?

Comment: Questions asking for debugging help should contain a [clear, verifiable and minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and include a desired behaviour. This provides nothing!

Comment: Also, this code is completely unreadable. Indent it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java introduced (rather late) typing of collection items like `Vector` of `Object`s as `Vector<T>`, where `T` is a type parameter given, like `Vector<String>`. (It is called *generic typing*.)

Now the compiler can "check" whether the item types are alright.

```
class Traversor<T> extends Thread {

    Enumeration<T> e;

    public Traversor(Enumeration<T> e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("new thread started, traversing vector  elements.....");
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(e.nextElement());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        System.out.println("new thread completed");
    }
}

class VectorTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("main thread started, creating vector...");
        Vector<String> v = new Vector<>();
        v.addElement("one");
        v.add("three");
        v.add(1, "two");

        Enumeration<String> e = v.elements();
        System.out.println("vector created ,enumeration obtained");
        Traversor<String> th = new Traversor<>(e);
        th.start();
        System.out.println(" new thread launched , suspending main thread");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        System.out.println("main thread resumed,modifying vector");
        v.add("four");
        v.add("five");
        System.out.println("vector modified, main thread completed");
    }
}
```

By the way Vector and Enumeration are rather old. Actually one seldom sees Vector nowadays.

```
// Alternative to Vector:
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("alpha");
for (String s : list) { ... }

// Alternative to Enumeration:
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
     String s = iterator.next();
}
```